# Negative Zero in the set of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

So according to the laws of algebra for a given $x$, one denotes by $-x$ the number such that $x+y = 0$ and is called negative of x. The subtraction operation is given by $z - x = z + (-x)$.

It is easy to prove that $-0 = 0$, thus they have the same value. But this mean that -0 and 0 are equivalent or are they different elements, $-0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $-0 = 0$?

Comment: A related question: are $-(-1)$ and $1$ equivalent or equal?

Comment: What did you think "equal" meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since two objects are equal if and only if they are the same objects, $-0$ and $0$ are in fact the same object.

And just because you can write something in several ways doesn't mean each way gives off a different object. $2=1+1$ and $4=2+2=2\cdot 2=2^2=\sqrt{15+1}$.

Comment: Can you prove that if two elements are equal, then they are the same element? :)

Comment: @Alexey: Prove it from what? Thin air? Probably not. From the axioms of classical first-order logic with equality and the definition of a structure and interpretation in logic? Yes. From the axioms of $\sf ZFC$? Also yes.

Comment: Well, judging by the upvotes, i thought that there were some content in the question, and there were something to prove...

Comment: But in any case i think that "equality" did not always mean "identity".

Comment: Similarly, $1$ and $0.999\ldots$ are precisely the same object. So, e.g., $\lfloor0.999...\rfloor=1$.

Comment: @Alexey In general "equality" and "identity" denote the same term. In some contexts, they do mean different things. This is in the case that we have some mathematical theory in which we are defining some object, but want to define "equality." In this restricted case, "equality" is whatever our definition is, and "identity" means that they are constructed exactly the same. For more about this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation